# Bootstrap css conflict in wordpress admin page

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

if I enqueue Bootstrap CSS to my admin header it 'll apply to all options including my admin page.

```
add_action('admin_head', array(&$this,'enqueue_style_menu'));


public function enqueue_style_menu(){
    wp_register_style('ps-admin-css',plugins_url('css/admin-style.css', dirname(__FILE__)));
    wp_enqueue_style('ps-admin-css');
}
```

this is my code is this is the right way to enqueue scripts to WP admin page?

Comment: do you want to customize your admin page using custom CSS ? You do not need to enqueue jquery again. Because in Wordpress jquery file is already there. Refer to this https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_enqueue_scripts/

Comment: ya, I want to customize, and I did, but it applying to all, ex: plugin list also showing bold

Comment: but if I removed that enqueue_scripts_menu() method my jquery functions don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check below code:

```
function load_custom_wp_admin_style($hook) {
    // Load only on ?page=mypluginname
    if($hook != 'toplevel_page_mypluginname') {
            return;
    }
    wp_enqueue_style( 'custom_wp_admin_css', plugins_url('admin-style.css', __FILE__) );
}

add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'load_custom_wp_admin_style' );
```

Source: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts